# Take input from comboBox and split it so I get the price of the selected item

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a comboBox where the user can select from a variety of drinks

```
comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("");
comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Soda $1.95");
comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Tea $1.50");
comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Coffee $1.25");
comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Mineral Water $2.95");
comboBoxBeverage.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBoxBeverage.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

but I want to take the option selected in the combobox and split it so I can use the price.

I tried doing

```
double beverage;
beverage = double.Parse(comboBoxBeverage.Text.TrimStart(new[] { '$' }));
labelSubtotal.Text = beverage.ToString();
```

but it's giving me an error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: What's the error it's giving you?

Comment: during debugging it's giving me "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Comment: I'd use a datasource from the DB or List<T> so I could show `DisplayMember` to the user and get the price from the `ValueMember`.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  `it's giving me an error` is not the least bit helpful in describing the problem

Comment: A primitive way would be `var strPrice = text.Split('$').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 3):

A more OOP approach to your question and also removing the problem of parsing the input text is the following:

First create a class Beverage

```
public class Beverage
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"{this.Description} {(this.Price != 0 ? this.Price.ToString("C") : "")}";
    }
}
```

now create a `List<Beverage>` with your data

```
List<Beverage> drinks = new List<Beverage>()
{
    new Beverage {Description = "", Price = 0m},
    new Beverage {Description = "Soda", Price = 1.95m},
    new Beverage {Description = "Tea", Price = 1.50m},
    new Beverage {Description = "Coffee", Price = 1.25m},
    new Beverage {Description = "Mineral Water", Price = 2.95m}
};
comboBoxBeverage.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBoxBeverage.DataSource = drinks;
```

Now you can retrieve a Beverage instance from your combobox instead of a string and you get the Price directly from this Beverage instance

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                     
    if(comboBoxBeverage.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Beverage b = comboBoxBeverage.SelectedItem as Beverage;
        SubTotal += b.Price;
        labelSubtotal.Text = SubTotal.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

This solution works because the ComboBox calls ToString() for every item added to its list through the DataSource property unless you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties. 
Also notice that [when dealing with currency values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) you should use the decimal type, not the double type

Answer (score 0):

You might give this a shot. It just takes the selected item, splits it into two elements where the `$` is located, skips over the first element and assigns the second element's value to `itemPrice`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public double SubTotal { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("");
            comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Soda $1.95");
            comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Tea $1.50");
            comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Coffee $1.25");
            comboBoxBeverage.Items.Add("Mineral Water $2.95");
            comboBoxBeverage.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            comboBoxBeverage.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                     
            var itemPrice = comboBoxBeverage.Text.Split('$').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
            SubTotal += double.Parse(itemPrice);
            labelSubtotal.Text = "$" + SubTotal;
        }
    }
}
```